# What is the most efficient way to resolve a field in a Java object tree from a path string?

Tags: java, json, performance, serialization

**The Goal**

A templating engine that takes a document containing a number of *replacement sites* and a *context tree*. The replacement sites are of the form ${someObject.someProperty} and identify the target field using a dot-separated path notation similar to JavaScript's property accessors. The context tree is a simple hierarchy of POJOs like this:

```
public class ContextRoot {
    public SomeObject someObject;
    public OtherObject otherObject;
}

public class SomeObject {
    public String someProperty;
}

public class OtherObject {
    public Integer count;
}
```

An instance of a class like ContextRoot is fed into the templating engine along with the templated document and the product is a document where all of the substitution strings have been replaced with the value of the property they resolve to.

**What I've Tried**

Currently, our solution uses a Jackson JSON ObjectMapper to convert our ContextRoot object into a Map. From this point, we use the jayway/JsonPath library to resolve the value of the property referenced by a path. This is working quite well, but I've become concerned that the performance of this method may be sub-optimal since Jackson may or may not be converting the context object to an intermediate JSON representation before deserializing it back into a Map.

**The Question**

I have come across a number of solutions suggesting the use of native Java reflection to accomplish a similar goal. My concern with this approach is that I've been told reflection can be costly from a performance standpoint. Furthermore, rolling an in-house solution using this method would mean that we sacrifice Jackson's clever type-deduction and serialization logic; something we are not fond of reimplementing. Are there any other methods you can suggest to accomplish something like this?

**Further Information**

A point of clarification, while I'm never one to nitpick the performance of a solution that works and works well, this template engine runs while serving a client web request so we're trying to be a bit sensitive to where our response time goes.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an open source template engine, which would do this for you?

Comment: No *good* reason other than the usual corporate political pressures and the fact that the foundation of this engine is functioning quite well for us. This is a new enhancement we've been tasked with and we're getting perfectly acceptable performance from it, but I think it could be much better.

Comment: How do you think *"Jackson's clever type-deduction and serialization logic"* works? Using reflection. So you're already taking the perceived reflection performance hit, but Jackson does so much more and is even slower than just using reflection directly. The slow part is really not the reflection, but the parsing of the `${someObject.someProperty}` expression, and the data conversions you go through to convert your data to JSON.

Comment: Totally aware that Jackson makes prodigious use of reflection for type deduction.

My question revolved around what performance hits or bumps we might incur by dropping the overhead involved in the conversion of our POJO tree to a map structure. If we can resolve a given field by simply walking the tree using reflection, this would seem the better solution. However, I'd not tackled an application of reflection quite like this and so referred to the community for some wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been solved many times over, in every Java template engine under the sun. Therefore, you can get a well tested solution simply by using an existing mature template engine (such as FreeMarker, Velocity, JMustache, StringTemplate, ...). If that is not possible due to "political pressures", you might still be able to learn from their implementation.

In short: Yes, reflection is the way to go, that's what Jackson does, too. However, for high performance use of reflection, it is important to cache the `Method` or `Field` objects, and disable redundant access checks using `setAccessible(true)`. Monomorphic call sites would even enable inlining of the reflective access, but this is usually hard to accomplish, and therefore usually not worth it.

Finally, I think it is important to realize that most template engines spend more time copying strings into the output that accessing model objects, so it is quite possible you are optimizing the wrong part of your custom template engine.

Comment: Excellent information and valuable tips regarding access checks. We implemented a naive solution to our problem using reflection and walking the object hierarchy to locate fields but even with caching the fields (which, as it turns out, are rarely re-accessed during the course of a single rendering) we're finding the performance a bit lacking. 

The actual field locating is completely overwhelmed by, as you so rightly pointed out, the process of accurately mapping path segments to fields, properly formatting the stringified values and writing the string outputs. 

Thanks again!